# Unexpected end of input on remote server only

Tags: javascript

Here is my **entire** `.slider.js` file:

```
var sindex = 1;
var x = $('.sliderimg').length;
$('#countb').text(x);

$('#btnright').click(function(){
    if (sindex == x){sindex = 1;}
    else {sindex += 1;}
    $('#counta').text(sindex);
    //$('#counta').text($('.sliderimg').eq(sindex-1).attr('src'));
    $('.sliderimg').hide().eq(sindex-1).show();
});

$('#btnleft').click(function(){
    if (sindex == 1){sindex = x;}
    else {sindex -= 1;}
    $('#counta').text(sindex);
    //$('#counta').text($('.sliderimg').eq(sindex-1).attr('src'));
    $('.sliderimg').hide().eq(sindex-1).show();
});
```

On localhost there is no error but on remote server I'm getting errors:

Chrome:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` - `slider.js:2`

Firefox:
`SyntaxError: missing } after function body` - `slider.js:2:218`
`note: { opened at line 2, column 30` - `slider.js:2:30`

Any help?

Comment: It sounds like the code on your server is not the same as the code you have locally.  Double and triple and quadruple check it.  Check it in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: See what happens if you change that `//` comment to a `/* ... */` comment.

Comment: @dsh, you're right, `slider.js` on remote server was different, some lines where missing, I don't know why. I copied the code from local file and it works. Uploading again local files using FileZilla - again the same problem.

Comment: `Uploading again local files using FileZilla - again the same problem.` What does that mean? Does that mean you fixed the problem, or did you upload the "working file" properly this time, and it still gives the `exact` same error messages?

Comment: @Martin, I didn't check if the same lines of code are missing, but browsers show the same errors. Editing it, i.e. copying the local content directly on the server - it works. It seems some problem with FIleZilla.

Comment: @Pointy, I tried your solution and it works. What is the problem with one-line-comment?

Comment: @puerto something, I don't know what, is applying some sort of compression to the source code when you upload it. If the line endings are removed, then the `//` comment will apply to the entire rest of that function.

Comment: Ah i see, then it sounds like a caching issue most likely. Try to refresh without loading cached data (ctrl+ff5 in Chrome), after having uploaded the file that you know works. If you want to avoid caching issues like this with JS files that you might change in the future, add a `phantom/ghost string` to the file name using PHP, and using the `date()` function to get todays date, and time down to the very second. that means, that whenever the page is reloaded, the file name keeps changing, preventing it from getting cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the comments in your question, and the fact that you got it to work on `localhost`, but not on your `remote server`, could mean that your JS file has been `cached`, and is in fact using the `cached` version of the file online, reproducing the errors, despite them being fixed.

You could reload the page without cached content (ctrl+f5 in Chrome) after uploading the file you know works on `localhost`.

Then in the future, you could add a `phantom/ghost string`, also referred to as `cache-busting`, to the JS file, using PHP to `concatenate` the `date()` function to your filename, down to the very second (adding H:i:s). That way, the filename will have changed every second, so whenever the page is reloaded, it will have to get the new version of the JS file, preventing the user from ever using a cached version of the JS file.

Example of `phantom/ghost string`:

```
<script src="myscripts.js?<?php echo date('y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>"></script>
```

This should only be used on files that you know will receive updates/changes in the future. There is no need to add this to static libraries etc.